# iOS, Swift Segmented Control, Container View - How to avoid loading both container views

Tags: ios, swift, uisegmentedcontrol, uicontainerview

I've a segmented control and two container views. When the main view is loaded both of these container views are also loaded. Is there a way to load only the selected view. Please see the attached image. When the main view loads both First & Second container views are loaded. I don't want both of these views to be loaded because in these container views I want to fetch data from API when the segment is selected. In each of these container views will add pull down to refresh to fetch the data from API and also to display the up to date data as it might change by the time user goes from one segment to another. Is it possible to do so?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can ,but a different way is to post a notification to when the segmented controll is switched and the view controller where you want to load api materials,you put an observer ,meaning when you switch the segmented controll.you fire the function in the viewcontroller which has the api retriving function

- add this is in viewdidload of the container view’s viewcontroller

NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(
            self,
            selector: #selector(shows),
            name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "shows"),
            object: nil
        )

- now every time you post a notification this function will run

  @objc func shows() {
    //the function will run here
      }
- when switching in segmented control just post a notification and the shows() will run

  NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name("shows"),object: nil)

Comment: Sorry it's not clear. If you don't mind then can you post code in swift? I'm still not sure how we will stop both view being loaded same time by default after adding observer?

Comment: How do you fetch your data from api,do you fetch the data (other than pulling down) using viewdidappear or viewididload,

Comment: I'm fetching data from API and decoding JSON in videDidLoad in all view controllers.

Comment: Then if you put the fetching code in shows function ,it will only fire when when you switch,you would still load both viewcontroller but you will only load data when you switch